# Bootstrap3 form does not keep it layout on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have crated a form containing a date line (day, month, year) and a line below with time (hour : minutes). The fields are text inputs because they should rarely be changed but just accepted and submit the form.

The layout looks like I want to have it, both on PC and tablets - but when using a mobile it puts all 5 input fields on a seperate line and in full width. Even when there is enough space on the mobile.

[Copy of my html](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEJxYE)

The snipplet below, inline shows it as it looks on mobile and as PC when in fullscreen. I would like it to look as on PC on mobile also.

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <div class="container">
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="flexinform" action="usr_flexin.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
   <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Dato</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="day" size="2" maxlength="2" value="17" onkeypress="return trapenter(month,event);" onchange="alertonchanges();" />
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="month" size="2" maxlength="2" value="02" onkeypress="return trapenter(year,event);" onchange="alertonchanges();" />
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="year" size="4" maxlength="4" value="2016" onkeypress="return trapenter(hour,event);" onchange="alertonchanges();" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
   <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Tid</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour" size="2" maxlength="2" value="23" onkeypress="return trapenter(minute,event);" onchange="alertonchanges();" />
   :
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="minute" size="2" maxlength="2" value="54" onkeypress="return trapenter(day,event);" onchange="alertonchanges();" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-3">
    <input type="submit" name="formflexin" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start">
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Nulstil" onclick="givefocus(minute)">
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
        </div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is mobile first, and on mobile this is typically the desired behavior. It's caused by the `.form-control` CSS setting `display: block;` and `width: 100%;`. These settings are removed via media queries at larger sizes.

Add the following CSS to override the default behavior for your form:

```
#flexinform input.form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```